# php обращение по ключу

Tags: php

```
$array = array(
    "20" => "10кк",
    "40" => "20кк",
    "60" => "30кк",
    "80" => "40кк",
);

if ($_POST['ik_am'] == '20' && $_POST['ik_am'] == '40' && $_POST['ik_am'] == '60' && $_POST['ik_am'] == '80') {
    $text = '.аз донат '.$_POST['ik_x_login'].' '.$array[$_POST['ik_am']];
} elseif ($_POST['ik_am'] == '50') {
    $text = '.setvip '.$_POST['ik_x_login'];
} else {
    $text = '.setprem '.$_POST['ik_x_login'];
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста мне нужно обращаться к array по ключу, попытался смудрить такой код но он не срабатывает(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_POST['ik_am']` не может быть одновременно и 20, и 40, и 60, и так далее. Заменить `&&` на `||`, или лучше на [in_array](http://php.net/in_array).

Вообще обычно делают намного иначе. Можно использовать `in_array`, но можно реализовать ту же логику более компактно:

```
$array = array(
    20 => '.аз донат %s 10кк',
    40 => '.аз донат %s 20кк',
    60 => '.аз донат %s 30кк',
    80 => '.аз донат %s 40кк',
    50 => '.setvip %s',
);

$ik_am = $_POST['ik_am']?? null;
$ik_x_login = $_POST['ik_x_login']?? 'UNKNOWN';
$message = $array[$ik_am]?? '.setprem %s';
$text = sprintf($message, $ik_x_login);
```

Comment: спасибо большое)

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '?'

Comment: @Михаил вероятно вы используете более старую версию php (http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce), используйте обычный тернарный оператор в таком случае.